# Coleman ct200u mini bike

Tags: motor-mounts

Hello my Coleman mini bike will start then slowly die out and I’m not sure what to do or what it could be? Any suggestions on what it could be? It was run strong for all yesterday and just need an answer. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fueling problem.  Assuming you have gasoline in it, you might check the fuel valve (if present) and the fuel line/fuel filter for kinks or clogs.

But more likely you have a carburetor problems likely caused by leaving ethanol-laced gasoline in it during storage.

You will probably want to disassemble and clean the carb and replace any damaged parts.